# Automatically create github repo, cool. But how to automatically do first commit

Tags: linux, git, bash, github

I'm writing a bash script to automatically setup a private github repo, as well as setup a [deployHQ](http://deployhq.com) project for the same. This works well. However I can not add the GitHub repository to deployhq (via bash script using curl api calls) seemingly because I figure that there hasn't been an initial commit yet.

The idea of the script is to set everything up initially. From GitHub to deployhq to uploading deployhq ssh-rsa keys to the github repository - For each client website we begin to work on.

I'm using API keys, and in particular I'm using a personal access token to send commands to GitHub.

So my question is, how do I setup a new repository on GitHub **with an initial commit**, before the project has even started? (in order to satisfy deployhq)

I figure I need to use the API key to do this, as to avoid any user prompts.

It could just be a simple `README.md` file.

This is what I'm using so far (which works).

Note: obviously this is just part of the script.

```
SETUP_GITHUB_PROJECT_JSON='{
"name": "'$DHQ_PROJECT_PERMALINK'",
"description": "This project is a test",
"private": "true"
}'

SETUP=`curl -X POST -d "$SETUP_GITHUB_PROJECT_JSON" -H "$HEADER_ACCEPT" -H "$HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE" -u $GITHUB_API_KEY:x-oauth-basic "$GITHUB_BASE_URL"user/repos`
```

Happy to clarify as needed.

Comment: Did you tried to automatise the repo creation ? Like this: create a local repo (`mkdir repo; cd $_; git init .`), add a dummy file (`touch README; git add README`), commit (`git commit -m "initial commit"`), add origin server (`git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git`) and push it (`git push origin master`).

Comment: Yes, however, it asks for username and password, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Create a ssh key and add it to github?

Comment: Are you sure a missing initial commit is the problem? That sounds surprising to me. An empty repo is just as valid to check out as a full repo (well I suppose unless you are expecting to check out `HEAD` which doesn't exist yet). The command `git commit -m 'Initial Commit' --allow-empty <<<$(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)` will create an *empty* initial commit for you though if you want/need to do that but you will still need to be able to commit it to the repository for this to work.

Comment: @anastymous maybe you should *clarify your question* with this statement (avoid password prompt thing). Also, maybe you can add what you've *already tried*, the result you've got and *why* it doesn't work as you want or doesn't fit your needs.